# Icon missing when application is launched

Tags: unity, icons, taskbar

I've created an application launcher in `/usr/share/applications` that launches rdesktop. The file specifies an icon name and I've added the icons to:

```
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/48x48/apps
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/22x22/apps
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/256x256/apps
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/32x32/apps
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/scalable/apps-extra
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/24x24/apps
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/16x16/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps
```

I then drug the launcher to the taskbar and the launcher with the correct logo is visible in the taskbar. However, when I start the task, a new icon is created in the taskbar, a square with a question mark in the center.

What icons do I need and where, so that the taskbar displays the correct icon for the application when it is launched?

The .desktop file contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Icon=mswindows
Type=Application
Categories=Network;
Exec=rdesktop win7shared1 -g 1680x1000

Name=win7shared1
GenericName=rdesktop
Comment=Open windows desktop

Keywords=Windows
StartupNotify=false
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What will most probably solve your problem is to do the following:

1. Open the application
2. When it is running, open a terminal and type:

   ```
   xprop WM_CLASS
   ```
3. Then click on the open application window.
4. The output will look like (example `gedit`):

   ```
   WM_CLASS(STRING) = "gedit", "Gedit"
   ```
5. Use the first part (in this case would be `gedit`), to compose a line in your `.desktop` file:

   ```
   StartupWMClass=<string>
   ```

   (replace `<string>` with the actual (first part of the) output of `xprop WM_CLASS`, e.g. `StartupWMClass=gedit`)

Now try again (you might have to log out / in), most likely the application will appear in the launcher under its own icon.

#### Explanation

- When an application starts up correctly from a launcher (`.desktop` file), but another icon appears *with only a generic icon* (question mark), it is most likely that the application window and the launcher do not connect for some reason, and the launcher does not recognize the application's window as "his". This is often the case when a script or a non- standard application (-command) is used. In those cases the `StartupWMClass=` line is often the solution.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. This resolved the problem. For the record, the WM_CLASS string was "rdesktop","rdesktop".

Comment: @clayton perfect, glad it worked.

Comment: Your step 2 can be reduced, as xprop lets you pass in the atom you want returned, running `xprop WM_CLASS` is enough

Comment: @johndrinkwater Absolutely, thanks for the hint. It is more than a year ago, over 14 months is like another person wrote it :). Will edit...

Comment: @jacob-vlijm :) just came across it while researching an awkward xprop behaviour

Comment: This got the icon back for me as long as I use the icon I created on the desktop. Still missing when I search for the application in the dashboard (using the same .desktop file in /usr/share/applications/), but at least I have an option now. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Good answer! I have two applications that runs the same `WM_CLASS`. Is it possible to keep their icons separate?

Comment: Thank you, this what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

for me `xprop|grep WM_CLASS` gave `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer", "jetbrains-pycharm-ce"` (I was having this issue with pycharm for python)

It was the `sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer` that I needed as the string in my .desktop file (without quotes) - Thanks!

Comment: I added `StartupWMClass=sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer` to mine and nothing happened! Is the `.desktop` file located in the home folder?

Answer (score 1):

After putting icons into the right place, you should simply restart xserver (logout and login back).
Also try to update icon cache (simply paste code below into terminal):

```
for d in ~/.icons/*; do gtk-update-icon-cache -f $d; done
for d in /usr/share/icons/*; do sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -f $d; done
```