# (Little) problem with .desktop configuration file

Tags: unity-dash, .desktop

I just installed mGBA 0.6.3 downloading .deb files and running `dpkg -i`. After that, I tried to create a `.desktop` file for it, and it seems to work: in Dash there is the correct icon and executable runs without issues.

Then I've dropped it on Desktop as I did with other apps in Dash but it shows a default icon and not the one I chose. What should I do to fix this little problem? I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04.5; ask me for any other piece of information needed.

In this case I do not think it is a duplicate of "[Icon missing when application is launched](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558098/icon-missing-when-application-is-launched)", because the icon is correctly displayed in the Launcher, in Dash but not as icon when dropped to Desktop (`xprop` output, in fact, is 'not found').

`.desktop` file full text:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=mGBA
Exec=mgba-qt
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/apps/mgba.png
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Game;
```

Comment: I would say that 512x512 is too big for the desktop. Try with a smaller version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

question does the desktop entry execute correctly?  if it does then right click on the icon and select properties and try changing the icon there.
good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by kc1di I tried to execute from Desktop icon and I noticed it wasn't executable. I ran `chmod +x` and this immediately solved the issue.