# Application icon not displaying for running app

Tags: icons, .desktop, dock

I created a .desktop file for an AppImage application that I downloaded. The icon I used for the application displays on the application screen and on the side-bar but not on the running application on the side-bar.

So when I click on the application it starts running and creates a new icon in the side-bar but the new icon has no image and does not display the one specified in the .desktop file. The main application icon still displays correctly but not the icon for the running application.

Hopefully this explanation makes sense...if not I can provide a screenshot to display what I am talking about.

Is there a way I can make the running application icon use the same icon as the docked application icon specified in the .desktop file?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Update: So I noticed this related post: [Icon missing when application is launched](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558098/icon-missing-when-application-is-launched?rq=1) which answers my question!

I needed to add:

```
StartupWMClass=<string>
```

to my .desktop file in order to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is can be because of you made typo in path or entered a wrong location. Be sure that you entered location from root, not like “~/foo/bar.blah”. Can you tell the file path that you entered in .desktop file?

Comment: But if the file path was wrong the icon would not work for the main application, which it does. It only does not work for the running application.