# How can I add an icon on the taskbar for a running application without icon?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, taskbar

Some applications run perfectly fine, however, they do not show any icon in the taskbar as shown below:

[image: Screenshot of the taskbar]

Notice that all the running applications have icons except the last one (see the arrow) where the application runs perfectly.

When I search for the application to run it, it has an icon, but once it is running it has no icon in the taskbar.

What is wrong? how can I fix that?

Comment: What is the application?

Comment: @David: It is an app that I have build using cmake.  I have added the icon using Menueditor software, but when it runs it doesn' show any icon. So my question is in general how to solve that issue

Comment: This should be stated in the body of the question.

Comment: @David: Could you please edit the post to include the screenshot? I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @David: I don't think it is necessary. Maybe it has something to do with Gnome itself?

Comment: @Iyachtharwanambarek I do think it is necessary as it most probably is not something to do with gnome itself.

Comment: @Bruni: Should I add the .desktop file?

Comment: @Iyachtharwanambarek The thing is, I do not believe that the icon in the bar comes from the .desktop file. If you change e.g. for an application that has an icon, the `icon=` part in the .desktop file, the icon will not change. This is why I would mention in the question, that the application is compiled from source and not installed.

Comment: @Bruni: I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue, thanks to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/558441/1474620)

I had just to add the following line to `.desktop` file of the application:

```
StartupWMClass=XXXXX
```

Where XXXXX is the name of the application in lower case without quotes, obtained by running  `xprop WM_CLASS` on the terminal and clicking on the application window.

Comment: Nice, though it does not work for me. Probably because I use wayland.

Comment: @Bruni: Have you tried this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/435159/493431 ?